# MySQL drop tables where engine is memory

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data base where I have permanent versions of tables that I make copies of and then convert to memory engine for faster performance.  Is there a way to delete all the tables in a db by engine type?  Something along the lines of:

```
drop * from db1 where engine = memory;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This belongs to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get list of table names with the following query:

```
select table_name 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'db1' and engine = 'memory';
```

And then generate a query to drop them. As far as I know you cannot use expression / subquery for a tablename in the drop statement, so you will have to use 2 queries or create a stored procedure for this.